# Accumulation point(s) of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Find the accumulation point(s) of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Let $A = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. We will denote our accumulation point(s) by $A^\prime$.

I have a suspicion that $A^\prime = A$, when $A = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ . Is this correct?

Comment: I think points of $\mathbb N$ should also be included, according to [this definition](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Accumulation_point) from the on-line Encyclopedia of Mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

No that is not correct,

Given any point $x\in\mathbb{R}$, since every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ different from $x$ itself (Using the fact that the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with  respect to the usual topology are union of open intervals) we get that the set of limit points of $A$ is all $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

No. Fix $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider sequences of the form $$m + \frac{1}{n}.$$ Each sequence converges to $m$, and thus each $m \in \mathbb{N}$ is an accumulation point for $A$. Therefore $A' = \mathbb{R}$.